# How can I define addEventListener('click' with an ancestoral node hierarchy

Tags: javascript

Introductory note:
It was suggested the question below was not clearly stated. I simply wish to define an addEventListener('click' trap that traverses three nodes. One of the two examples I present below runs through a (grand)parent id ('id="ArticleStyle"' in the article tag) -> traverses down node to its child 'h1' -> and then further down node to the h1 spawned child, 'a'. Which is, the 'a href' being clicked and listened for.

---

I have two js scripts properly working that serve my needs by luck alone; not by robust planning. Both I would like to contain and evaluate in a grandparent node/wrapper using that unique id as the defined starting point. It would be essential in the second script to do so since there would be over a hundred (and growing) unique ids needed; if it weren't for the fact I am succeeding by using 'h1'-'a'. Fortunately here, 'h1' is not yet used elsewhere.

The 'a' links in the first script (immediately below / and one of its two HTML blocks is included below that) are fortunately parented by just a total of four unique id allowing it to be functional without the attempted EVALUATION for HANDLING line commented out. Otherwise, if I used an 'a'-'img' (as I used 'hi'-'a' in the second script), there would be sucked in traffic on clicks to other page navigation icons based on their similar 'a'-'img' coding. I would hope to use the attempted line of code I commented out, code it correctly and have it create a container/wrapper/node representing a lineage of 'div class="flagLinkVIEW"'-'a'-'img' || 'div class="flagLinkVIEW"'-'a'-'span' as a filter where none else enter in.

```
<script>
    //Toggles between Montage and Montage_VIEW based on, clicking the img icon.png or the span text below it

    document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {

        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! FIX 'IF' LINE COMMENTED OUT in second line below this !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //Code incorrectly formatted in line under this comment
        //if ((target.matches('.flagLinkVIEW a > img')) || (target.matches('.flagLinkVIEW a > span'))) {        

            if (target.parentElement.id === "VIEW_topIconOnOff0") {
                sessionStorage.displayStateMontage = "idMontage_VIEW";
                document.body.style.background = "white";
            }
            if (target.parentElement.id === "VIEW_topIconOnOff1") {
                sessionStorage.displayStateMontage = "idMontage";
                document.body.style.background = "rgb(225, 213, 191)";
            }
            if (target.parentElement.id === "VIEW_btmIconOnOff0") {
                sessionStorage.displayStateMontage = "idMontage_VIEW";
                document.body.style.background = "white";
            }
            if (target.parentElement.id === "VIEW_btmIconOnOff1") {
                sessionStorage.displayStateMontage = "idMontage";
                document.body.style.background = "rgb(225, 213, 191)";
            }

        //}
        //!!!!!!!!!!!Above is the closing bracket of the FIX 'IF' LINE COMMENTED OUT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    });
</script>




<div id="Icons-midNAV" class="IconOpacityControl-p5 LNKiconCOLORS">   
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open ('./Poetry%20-%20Montage%20of%20the%20Years_files/PDF%20-%20MASTER%20Montage%20of%20the%20Years.pdf', 'PDF Master',
    'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=100,left=260,height=420,width=420'); return false;">
    <img class="PDF-IconBC-Pv" src="./b-pdf_w.png" alt="PDF Master" />
    <span class="BtmCtrIconTextStyle PDF-TextBC-Pv">MASTER</span></a>

    <div class="flagLinkVIEW">
        <!-- Instead of class, which would be nice, I could if must, use a unique id of
        flagLinkVIEW_A here if necessary, and elsewhere in the second similar block, an
        id of flagLinkVIEW_B. It would be instructive though, to solve with a class example. -->

        <a id="VIEW_btmIconOnOff0" href="./Poetry%20-%20Montage%20of%20the%20Years.html"> 
        <img class="VIEW-IconBC-pV" src="./binoculars-detail-2A.png" alt="Basic-VIEW" />
        <span class="BtmCtrIconTextStyle VIEW-TextBC-pV">BasicVIEW</span></a>

        <a id="VIEW_btmIconOnOff1" href="./Poetry%20-%20Montage%20of%20the%20Years.html"> 
        <img class="VIEW-IconBC-pV" src="./binoculars-detail-2A.png" alt="Basic-VIEW" />
        <span class="BtmCtrIconTextStyle VIEW-TextBC-pV">FullVIEW</span></a>

    </div>

</div>
```

The solution I seek for the second script I believe is similar. Here I would wish use the unique id attached to the article node. I would hope to incorporate the incorrectly coded line now commented out, and fix it to contain a specified node lineage of 'article id="ArticleStyle"'-'h1'-'a' and use it as a filter where none else enter in. Again, the js script is immediately below with the HTML following it.

```
<script>
    //Sets localStorage to transfer present sessionStorage to a new _blank tab/window being opened

    document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {

    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Change line below to a correctly syntaxed lineage of: 
    //if ((target.matches('#ArticleStyle h1 > a')) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if (target.matches('h1 a')) {
            localStorage.previousMenu = sessionStorage.previousMenu;
            localStorage.motherMenu = sessionStorage.motherMenu;
            localStorage.rootMenu = sessionStorage.rootMenu;
        }
    });
</script>




<article id="ArticleStyle">
<h1 style="line-height:0; padding-top:1.8em">
  <a href="./Poetry%20-%20Black%20Holes%20and%20When%20Time%20Stands%20Still.html" target="_blank">
  Black Holes and When Time Stands Still</a></h1>

<!--multiple 'h1' child nodes, as above but with differing URLs -->
</article
```

Comment: The `localStorage/sessionStorage` Objects makes no sense syntactically...unless there is other code that is using the prototype of said Objects.

Comment: I am only presenting snippets.  sessionStorage is set in a major linked sort.js file and used actively in a first in last out stack to display historically meaningful navigation links at the bottom of the HTML page and display:none to the other choices. The transfer you refer to works syntactically in that when the page as exampled opens a link to a new content page, I have chosen to open it in a new tab window with _blank. It thus brings with it no sessionStorage. I have made temporary use of localStorage to hold the Menu history stack: when the new page opens, transfer to its sessionStorage

Comment: I read `redirectsNavStackSort.js` I see what it's doing now. Some of the `if` conditions are using `&` as an operator `&&` is the correct syntax for AND gate. In general it'd be better if you use classes and all of the ids you use for data use `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: Yeah, well it's not completely clear what the question is because the overall purpose of the code is not clear. [`&` is a bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND)

Comment: Thank you for the in depth interest. This thread, however, is completely sidetracking away from the requested answer. Your observation regarding the & believe it or not, after much testing and an involvement with an other stack overflow discussion, in this isolated but relevant multiple comparison case, the & and not the && was the ultimate ticket. As you can see elsewhere, all code is based on the overall preferred use of && !== === I have tried to use id and class wisely. You are correct, using dataValue instead designating it idValue would have been cleaner verbiage.

Comment: Sorry if there is any lack of clarity of the question. I simply wish to define a 'click' trap that traverses three nodes. One of the two examples I presented runs through a (grand)parent id ('ArticleStyle' in the article tag) -> traverses down node to its child 'h1' -> and then further down node to the h1 spawned child, 'a'. Which is, the a-href being clicked.

Comment: It should be `if ((target.matches('#ArticleStyle h1 > a')) {...` the selector is wrong. It's not `.ArticleStyle` it's `#ArticleStyle`. A dot: `.` prefix is for class and a hash:`#` is for id.

Comment: Thank you for your follow up. You comment is certainly true to the commented out, dangling pseudo code line from many variations and tries that came to the point requesting help. I tried it exactly as you suggested, and like the earlier answer from@ suryapratap, it fails. Syntactically, it aborts the script.

Comment: Not affecting the validity of the question, or its need for an answer, I did offer a wrong assumption in a comment above. Contrary to what I had concluded in my research, sessionStorage DOES SEEM TO TRANSFER FROM ITS PARENT (not just in a window overwrite with target="_self"); but, even in a new tabbed window using target="_blank", and too in a whole new /~href="#" onclick="window.open~/ in a separately created window popup session.

Comment: The `window` Object is the *"parent"* of everything within the DOM and beyond the browser. What you observed is just the extent of `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` Objects *"scope"* (probably not the right term but it's common definition is appropriate). These objects will store strings for each domain it was called from. So if you saved a string on `https://example.com/path/to/index.html` you can be at `https://example.com/root.html` and get that exact string, but not if your browser was at `https://web.com` or anywhere else unless the host is `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//Sets localStorage to transfer present sessionStorage to a new _blank tab/window being opened

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {

    //!!!!!!!!!!!!Change line below to: if ((target.matches('.ArticleStyle h1 > a'))
    if (target.closest('.ArticleStyle h1 > a')) {
        localStorage.previousMenu = sessionStorage.previousMenu;
        localStorage.motherMenu = sessionStorage.motherMenu;
        localStorage.rootMenu = sessionStorage.rootMenu;
    }
});
</script>
```

Maybe your are looking for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest still i would try to have classes or ids on my layout and put different handlers instead of in body

Comment: The answer you proposed, unfortunately, does not work. When put in place, it blocks the click from passing through to the three code lines below it, and the transfer to localStorage does not take place as intended. Thank you @suryapratap for the glimmer of hope. And, too for the good article based on navigating a nested hierarchy of individually id tagged nodes.